# Is there a word in latin for "type"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, modern-life

I'd like to know if there's a latin word for type. That sort of person that one is attracted to. Like "You ain't my type". I thought that the word "typus" could be used, but it basically means a figure, image on a wall, and also has a medical meaning which I believe can't be used.

Comment: Keep in mind that "my type" is idiomatic English that usually means "the type of person I like" rather than literally "the same type of person as I am".

Comment: This word has the same meaning in Portuguese, as well. "Tipo" That's why I thought about the latin word with gave us "type" and "tipo".

Comment: The ancients had their four temperaments, but for men only.

Comment: Latin typically likes to use relative conjunctions and their correlatives: *qualis talis* or even more commonly *cuiusmodi eiusmodi*. Do you really need a noun?